# How to change Reset Password URL in Devise RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to change the url of password reminder made by RoR.
More detail, want to insert I18n.locale following domain. Let's say

```
ttp://mydomain.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=gPudhxxxxxx2xTZ4hBeHeA
```

to

```
ttp://mydomain.com/en/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=gPudhxxxxxx2xTZ4hBeHeA
```

In my reset_password_instructions.html.slim, code is like this.

```
p
  = (I18n.t "resetpassword_mailbody", email: @resource.email).html_safe
p
  = link_to (I18n.t "change_my_passwd"), edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token)
p
  = (I18n.t "mail_footer").html_safe
```

Need I override edit_password_url?
What should I do? Please give me some advise.

Answer (score 0):

Change the routes for password controller with devise.

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'cutom_url', to: 'devise/passwords#edit', as: :edit_user_registration
end
```

[Reference link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)

Comment: Sorry, my description is bit difficult. Basically, the code above provides "htp://mydomain.com/users/password/edit....". But I'd like to change this to "htp://mydomain.com/en/users/password/edit....". In short, want to put locale into path. Is it possible?

Comment: You needs skip password routes that devise provide us and creates new custom routes

`devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}, skip: [ :passwords ]`

`get "/en/users/password/edit" => "devise/passwords#edit"`

Comment: Thanks. I finally found how to fix it. It's a matter of edit_password_url. I'll describe in the questionnaire.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how.

```
p
  = link_to (I18n.t "change_my_passwd"), edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token, locale: I18n.locale)
```